# How to override batch_action(ActiveAdmin) and pass the object there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have this in index do

```
column I18n.t('active_admin.delete') do |author|
  link_to I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), admin_author_path(author),
          method: :delete, data: { confirm: t('admin.authors.confirmations', quantity: author.books.count) }
end
```

but I need this action in batch_action in - > " confirm: .... "

```
batch_action :destroy, confirm: 
      I18n.t('admin.authors.confirmations', quantity: ) do |ids|
    Author.find(ids)
```

I select (batch_action) author (checkbox) and click "delete selected" and in dialog window(in confirm message) need to pass  "quantity: author.books.count"

Comment: batch_action is from Active Admin, isn't it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev    yes, ActiveAdmin.register

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this is impossible. The rendering of that button/form is disconnected (on several levels) from clicking it.

Most importantly, the rendering happens first. And the user might not even select *any* rows while on the page. So how is the server to know what number to render?

The easiest way would be to not use the quantity in the message here. If not acceptable, then I'd try to change the button's `data-confirm` on the client side before posting the form.